# Are the r.v. such that their sum produces the same distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, soft-question

Suppose, $X_1,X_2$ are i.i.d random variables with some distribution $F_X(x)$.
Let $Y=X_1+X_2$. Does there exist $F_X(x)$ such that $F_X(x)=F_Y(x)$ or maybe $F_X(x)=F_Y(x)$ a.e.?

Thanks. Sorry, for the vague question I am still trying to formalize it.I will be happy to answer any of your questions.

Comment: $X_1=X_2=0$ works, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. But this one is trivial. But thanks.

Comment: 11 minutes. $ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X_1$ is square integrable, then we have $EY^2 = 2EX_1^2$. If $X_1$ and $Y$ have the same distribution function, they have the same second moment, so the only possibility is $EX_1^2 = 0$, i.e. $X_1 = 0$ almost surely.

If $X_1$ is not square integrable but $E|X|<+\infty$, from $EY = E(X_1 + X_2) = EX_1$, we get $EX_1=EX_2 = 0$, then we have $E(Y|X_1) = X_1$, which means the conditional expectation of $Y$ has the same distribution with $Y$, then from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008727/conditional-expectation-equals-random-variable-almost-sure/1016939#1016939), we have $Y= X_1$ almost surely, i.e. $X_2 = 0$ almost surely.

So $X_1 = X_2 = 0$ is the only possibility for $L^1$ variable

Comment: And not L^1? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not without any renormalization.

Indeed, if for instance
$$
E[X^2]<\infty
$$then you should have
$$
\text{var }X = \text{var }X_1 + \text{var }X_2= 2\text{var }X
$$leading to $\text{var }X = 0$.

---

if you allow an identity such as
$$
X_1 + X_2 = aX
$$then there are several example of such distributions:
the [Normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), and the [Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).

---

For more information on this subject, you can take a look at [the wikipedia page about stable distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution).

Answer (score 2):

The result holds without integrability condition:

Consider the characteristic function $\varphi$ of $X$, defined for every real number $x$ by $\varphi(x)=E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm ixX})$, then the hypothesis implies the identity $$\varphi(x)=E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix(X_1+X_2)})=E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm ixX_1})E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm ixX_2})=\varphi(x)^2,$$ for every $x$, hence $\varphi(x)\in\{0,1\}$. One knows that $\varphi(0)=1$ and that $\varphi$ is continuous hence $\varphi(x)=1$ for every $x$. As the name suggests, $\varphi$ *characterizes* the distribution of $X$ and the Dirac mass at zero has this characteristic function hence $X=0$ almost surely.